# Using mathbb{1} with IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran

Is there a way to get `$mathbb{1}$` to work using the IEEE style file? I have found that this works with other style files, but not with the IEEE style file. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\title{Writing mathbb 1}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  We show a test case for the inability of writing mathbb 1 using IEEEtran.cls.
   \end{abstract}
   \begin{IEEEkeywords}
     mathbb
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Illustration}
The mathbb command \begin{verbatim} ${\mathbb 1}$ \end{verbatim} does
not appear to work in the {\tt IEEEtran.cls} file. The above provides the
following symbol, that is often used as an indicator function:
$${\mathbb 1}.$$
However, a similar approach works for other letters, {\em e.g.}, 
\begin{verbatim} ${\mathbb I}$ \end{verbatim} provides
$${\mathbb I}.$$
so some other additional device/fix may need to be found.
\end{document}
```

which provides the following PDF for me:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some examples in Page 124 in `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\doc\latex\comprehensive\symbols-a4.pdf`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
$\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
$\mathbb{0123456798}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use NewTX (that provides symbols compatible with Times), there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Writing mathbb 1}
\author{author}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
We show a test case for the ability of writing mathbb 1 using \texttt{IEEEtran.cls}.
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
mathbb
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Illustration}

The mathbb command \verb|$\mathbb{1}$| appears to work in the 
\texttt{IEEEtran.cls} file. The above provides the
following symbol, that is often used as an indicator function:
\[
\mathbb{1}.
\]
A similar approach works for other letters, \emph{e.g.}, 
\verb|$\mathbb{I}$| provides
\[
\mathbb{I}.
\]
so no other additional device/fix is needed.

\end{document}
```

##### Important notes

The correct syntax is

- `\mathbb{1}` or `\mathbb{A}`, not `{\mathbb 1}` or `{\mathbb A}`
- `\texttt{words}` and not `{\tt words}`
- `\emph{words}` and not `{\em words}`
- `\[...\]` and not `$$...$$`

[image]